# How to have an L shaped layout with pack?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    rgb = {'red', 'green', 'blue'}
    frames = dict()
    for color in rgb:
        frames[color] = tk.Frame(root, height=64, width=64, bg=color)
    frames['red'].grid(row=0, column=0)
    frames['green'].grid(row=1, column=0)
    frames['blue'].grid(row=1, column=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

which uses `grid` for its layout. How can I have the same, L shaped, layout using only `pack` instead and *without* using additional widgets?

`Frames`' parent(not necessarily a top-level) will have only those 3 `Frames` as children. Ideally the layout should be resizeable.

Comment: if you're asking how to make an L shape - try columnspan=2 or rowspan=2 -...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frames['red'].pack(anchor=tk.W)
frames['green'].pack(side=tk.LEFT)
frames['blue'].pack()
```

But why would you want to? It's much easier to use Frames for the things that fall into neat rows or columns, and then pack the those into more complex structures.

Comment: I tried to solve a similar question, but couldn't. Wondered if it was at all possible, apparently, it is. Besides, I think this may be a good dupe-loc for stubborn questions demanding `pack`. Thanks.

Comment: Any scalable way, btw?

Comment: As soon as you resize the window you'll see this isn't the same at all.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, if you want each frame to take up 1/4th of the screen and expand when the window resizes, `pack` is simply not able to do it. There is no way with `pack` and no extra frames to get the upper-left widget to take up 1/4th of the screen when you resize the window.

Tkinter has both `pack` and `grid` because they solve two different types of layout problems. If they could easily solve all of the same problems there would be no need to have them both.

Answer (score 0):

It *can't* be done. Below demo displays all shapes possible for every `side` option:

```
import tkinter as tk


class ParentFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self._colors = ('red', 'green', 'blue')
        self._c_len = len(self._colors)
        self.labels = dict()
        self._i = 0
        self._create_widgets()
        self.side_combinations()


    def _create_widgets(self):
        for _color in self._colors:
            self.labels[_color] = tk.Label(self, height=16, width=16,
                                                fg='white', bg=_color)


    def side_combinations(self):
        _side_opts = ('top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right')
        _o_len = len(_side_opts)
        if self._i < (_o_len**3):
            _cur_opt = dict()
            _cur_opt['red'] = _side_opts[self._i//(_o_len**2)]
            _cur_opt['green'] = _side_opts[(self._i//_o_len) % _o_len]
            _cur_opt['blue'] = _side_opts[self._i%_o_len]

            for _clr in self._colors:
                self.labels[_clr].pack(side=_cur_opt[_clr])
                self.labels[_clr]['text'] = _cur_opt[_clr]

            self._i += 1
            self.after(250, self.side_combinations)
        else:
            self._i = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    test = ParentFrame(root)
    test.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```