# Align a button to the bottom, Using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone help me to align the button to the bottom of the screen in Tkinter. I am following a youtube tutorial, and in their code they write what i have written, but it aligns the button to the bottom. I am Using python 3.7 on a mac

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() #makes a blank popup, under the variable name 'root'

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button1 = Button(topFrame, text='Button 1', fg='red')
button2 = Button(topFrame, text='Button 2', fg='blue')
button3 = Button(topFrame, text='Button 3', fg='green')
button4 = Button(topFrame, text='Button 4', fg='pink')

button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop() #loops the program forever until its closed
```

Comment: What's the result you're expecting? I'm getting four buttons horizontally aligned, from left to right. Do you want them to be vertically aligned?

Comment: Is the button you want at the bottom supposed to be in `bottomFrame`, or is it supposed to be above or below `bottomFrame`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add `button4` to `bottomFrame`:

```
button4 = Button(bottomFrame, text='Button 4', fg='pink')
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be considered impractical in most cases but one way would be to simply swap the line of:

```
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
```

with:

```
button4.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Which would make it so that `button4` fills the first empty space, as opposed to the last, in the *"cavity"* further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48714635/7032856).

Comment: I was struggling to get a button underneath 2 left-aligned frames and this did it!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `grid()` rather than `pack()`, it allows positioning to be much more controllable.

The `grid()` method creates a sort of table with rows and columns that allows you to position your elements.

Here is the sort of layout I have in mind:

```
 -----
|A|B|C|
 -----
| |D| |
 -----
```

- **A**: Row 1, column 0
- **B**: Row 1, column 1
- **C**: Row 1, column 2
- **D**: Row 2, column 1

If this is not what you want your elements to look like please edit your post or comment and I will edit my answer accordingly.

---

Bearing that in mind we can change `.pack()` to this method:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() #makes a blank popup, under the variable name 'root'

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button1 = Button(topFrame, text='Button 1', fg='red')
button2 = Button(topFrame, text='Button 2', fg='blue')
button3 = Button(topFrame, text='Button 3', fg='green')
button4 = Button(topFrame, text='Button 4', fg='pink')

button1.grid(column=0, row = 1)
button2.grid(column=1, row = 1)
button3.grid(column=2, row = 1)
button4.grid(column=1, row = 2)

root.mainloop() #loops the program forever until its closed
```

**`pack()` and `grid()` cannot be used together, you either have to use one or the other.**

I also advise against `from tkinter import *` this is unsafe and may override functions and will most likely at some point cause you problems.

Comment: Independently of the preferred geometry manager,, I keep thinking that button4 should be added to bottomFrame.

Comment: How is `from tkinter import *` not thread-safe?

Comment: @davidedb You are quite right, that fixes the issue.  I was just listing another way to go around solving the problem.

Comment: @Rightleg  My mistake `from tkinter import *` is unsafe and may overwrite functions, tkinter is not thread safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168346/python-tkinter-with-threading-causing-crash